# DalvikVM getting disconnected while debugging

Tags: android, debugging, localhost, dalvik

Hi I have some break points in my project. The debugging has to be done on a Service class.I have added the  android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(); to the code to enable debugging. But even then while debugging it is getting disconnected/terminated often. Any solutions for this. Thanks

Comment: What do you see in logcat when it terminates?